# COM RCW - ActiveX Component can't create object

Tags: .net, com, vb6, rcw

I have one COM component - "ProgramA.dll"
This COM component is internally referencing "ProgramB.dll", and creating an instance of underlying object as follow:

```
Public Sub AddData()
Dim..... 
.......
    Set objClassA = New ProgramB.clsClassA
.....
End Sub
```

I have added a reference of ProgramA.dll in my .NET application (and also added a reference of ProgramB in .NET app).

When I call "AddData()" method of ProgramA through my .NET application, then its failing while trying to create instance of ProgramB.clsClassA, it is giving an error saying "AcitveX component can't create object"

What could be the possible reason, or what changes I require to do?

Comment: Have you registered your `ProgramB.dll` via `regsvr32`?

Comment: is ProgramB.dll a COM dll? if so, is it registered properly?

Comment: thanks, i will try out registering ProgramB.dll and will update you.. but why the question is downvoted? the one who downvoted, can u please give any valid reason?

Comment: I don't see the VB6 question here.

Comment: and so you downvoted... isn't COM anywhere related to VB 6?

Comment: i dont understand what's the problem with the question.. pls don't downvote just because you have that authority.. ppl do a lot effort to earn each point and they shouldn't be deducted just for the sake of it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I registered ProgramB.dll using regsvr32 and it worked.